# Spring Serverless HTTP Poller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-function

> I want to implement a serverless function that polls an HTTP endpoint and publishes the response to a messaging queue.

> My initial thought is to build a spring boot application using spring integration gateway and adapters for HTTP polling and publishing to queue (and deploy as lambda). Is there a better option in the spring stack?

> I looked at spring cloud function, spring cloud stream, spring cloud task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Cloud Stream this type of microservice is called `source`. So, you need to have a `Supplier` bean based on Spring Integration Java DSL to build a simple flow to let Spring Cloud Stream to poll it periodically and produce a result into bound destination.

Something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingHttpFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Supplier.class, gateway -> gateway.beanName("httpSupplier"))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://somehost"))
                .get();
    }
```

See a blog post about this kind of interoperability: https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/25/spring-cloud-stream-and-spring-integration

Comment: I don't have input and return parameters. I read from application config (application.yaml), make an HTTP call and the send the result out via AMQP (all of this is a Spring Integration Flow). In this case how do I write the function as there is no return and no param , so can't use any of Function, Supplier, Consumer (I can use like a dummy return value and use Supplier, but does not make sense). What is he best way to implement this as AWS Lambda? May be I am missing something very basic? My entry point is a Gateway class with a method like getData(Collection configs).